# How to catch onKeyUp event on any HTML element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to listen a `keyup` event on a `<section></section>` HTML element in React. So far, I haven't been able to get it to work. Below, you'll find the code sample that handles the event:

```js
import React from "react"

function scrollTo(event) {
  // event.preventDefault()
  console.log(event.type)
}

const FullscreenBackground = () => (
  <section
    onWheel={scrollTo}
    onKeyUp={scrollTo}
  >
    // Content
  </section>
)

export default FullscreenBackground
```

I'm listening with no problems to the `onWheel` event, but I haven't got any luck with the `onKeyUp` one.

Comment: afaik, you can't attach keyboard event listeners to static elements like a section using react and you can only do it attaching them to inputs or things you can control

Comment: OK, that explains the problems I had. Would it work in plain JS ? Should I try to wrap the section in a `canva`?

Comment: you should use window.addEventLister to register keyboard events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `div` element cannot be given focus. You can make this div "selectable" by adding `tabIndex="0"` prop to `section` element.

```js
function scrollTo(event) {
  // event.preventDefault()
  console.log(event.type)
}

const FullscreenBackground = () => (
  <section
    onWheel={scrollTo}
    onKeyUp={scrollTo}
    tabIndex="0"
  >
    qweqweqweqweqwe
  </section>
)


ReactDOM.render(<FullscreenBackground />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Do the user needs to explicitly give focus to the `section` or can I do it programmatically?

Comment: @Gaspacchio You can focus that section element using react ref. But if you don't care about which element will trigger `onkeyup` event, then i suggest you to set onkeyup event on document element like that `document.onkeyup = () => { ... }` in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method

Comment: I think I'll set the watcher on the document since it will mostly be used to transition from screen to screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event on a document. check the snippet below.
To test the snippet click on the white area where you have "Key Code" and try to press a key.

```js
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
  $("p").html(event.which); // get the key code
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Key Code</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to written to work with React.

Comment: My bad i don't have any ReactJS environement to test it. It was a lil bit naive.